# Split by three spaces - batchscript

Tags: string, parsing, batch-file

I have a string like this.

```
adsads   d b c   dsad   ds   ads
```

How do I split this string (on 3 spaces) to obtain d b c from this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "string=adsads   d b c   dsad   ds   ads"

FOR /f "tokens=1delims=#" %%p IN ("%string:   =#%") DO ECHO token 1 is "%%p"
FOR /f "tokens=2delims=#" %%p IN ("%string:   =#%") DO ECHO token 2 is "%%p"
FOR /f "tokens=3delims=#" %%p IN ("%string:   =#%") DO ECHO token 3 is "%%p"
FOR /f "tokens=1,3delims=#" %%p IN ("%string:   =#%") DO ECHO token 1 is "%%p"; token 3 is "%%q"
GOTO :EOF
```

Here, `for /f` parses the string supplied (in quotes) and assigns the nominated token number to `%%p` (and if more than 1 *token* is specified to `%%q`, `%%r`...)

The string between the quotes is constructed by substituting `#` for <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> - # being a character that doesn't otherwise occur in the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "str=adsads   d b c   dsad   ds   ads"

set "i=1" & set "part[!i!]=%str:   =" & set /A i+=1 & set "part[!i!]=%"

echo part[2] = "%part[2]%"
```

If you want to know how this *simple* (one line) method works, just remove the `@echo off` line and carefully review the executed code! **`;)`**

Comment: Seeing as my answer uses the same method, is more complete and was posted first, would it not be better, _or more respectful_, to remove this answer?

Comment: @Compo: You are right! I didn't reviewed the other answers before post the mine. IMHO the simplicity of my answer is a bonus (but just the OP can answer this point). I never have seen an answer posted by someone else based on [my method](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429), although I posted it almost 3 years ago! From this point of view, would it not be more respectful to include a link to the original source?

Comment: I haven't stolen, plagiarised or attempted to seek credit for a method I didn't come up with. That said, I have used that method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/84404682?noredirect=1) before, and when asked how it works, I linked to 'your' method in explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to need the second "token". This is possible with simple substring substitution (no need for a `for` or delayed expansion)

```
set string=adsads   d b c   dsad   ds   ads

set string=%string:*   =%
set string=%string:   =&REM %
echo "%string%"
```

The first `set` removes from the start of string all until (including) the three spaces. The second one uses a parser trick to remove the next three spaces and anything after.

Comment: Sneeky, I like this method :)

Answer (score 0):

This is dependent on your current input as per question. in other words, the first 3 space will be matched until next 3 spaces.

```
@echo off
set "line=adsads   d b c   dsad   ds   ads"
set "line=%line:   =:%"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ("%line%") do (
echo %%b
)
```

Comment: ... and, after that, the `d b c` values, that was the only ones that was originally separated by one space, lost this feature and mix with the other values... **`:(`**

Comment: @Aacini yeah man, I completely scanned the question and thought he wanted to simply replaces 3 spaces with 1... suppose I can get a LOL? :) anyway, fixed my answer now. Thanks for informing me.

Answer (score 0):

You could set each token separated by three spaces as variables and just echo the one you want.

e.g.

```bat
Rem Turn off echoing of commands to the screen
@Echo Off
Rem enable delayed expansion
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Rem define a variable to hold the test string
Set "str=adsads   d b c   dsad   ds   ads"
Rem clear all variables beginning with `token`
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('"Set token 2>Nul"') Do Set "%%A="
Rem Starting token number
Set "i=1"
Rem Set each token separated by three spaces as a variable
Set "token!i!=%str:   =" & Set /A i+=1 & Set "token!i!=%"
Rem Exit if there token number was not incremented
If %i% Lss 2 Exit /B
Rem Show all token variables
Set token
Rem Echo only "token number 2"
Echo "%token2%"
Rem halt script to allow end user to read output
Pause
```

All lines beginning with `Rem` are for information only, they can be removed thus:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "str=adsads   d b c   dsad   ds   ads"

For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('"Set token 2>Nul"') Do Set "%%A="
Set "i=1"
Set "token!i!=%str:   =" & Set /A i+=1 & Set "token!i!=%"
If %i% Lss 2 Exit /B
Echo %token2%
Pause
```

Comment: You are borrowing [my method](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429)! **`;)`**