# Batch script - split by two or more spaces

Tags: string, batch-file, split, delimiter

I have a large string that looks like this

```
aa bb c d  f eeeee    ffff
```

I am not sure of the number of spaces that would come along with the string. The next time, string might have five spaces between aa and bb ansd so on...

```
aa     bb     c      f       eee ff
```

Is there a way I can split on two or more spaces (variable number of spaces) using delims in batch script?I always want the second token no matter how any spaces are there between first and second tokens.

PS : Edit
I want the second token (by token I mean the token obtained after splitting by exactly two or more spaces). My token itself can contain a single space. Example:  `a    b   c   d`. 
In this want to extract b. 
Another example: `a   b b    c             d` . 
In this I want to extract b b.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split by three spaces - batchscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808255/split-by-three-spaces-batchscript)

Comment: per definition, the "second token" is `bb`. Considering your last question: is that, what you want?

Comment: no matter how many spaces (looking specifically for two or more spaces) are present between tokens in the string, I always need 2nd token.

Comment: What's wrong then with `for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ("%string%") do echo %%a`?

Comment: My token can contain atmost one space. Token 2 can look like bb or b b. But strictly two spaces or more is the delimiter i wanted. Your step splits even 1 space as a delimiter I suppose.

Comment: So in your first example, you need `bb c d` (or `f eeeee`)? and in the second one `bb`? Please be exact. We try our best to read your mind, but our ability is a bit limited.

Comment: I want the second token (by token I mean the token obtained after splitting by exactly two or more spaces). My token itself can contain a single space. Example:  a    b   c   d. In this want to extract b. Another example: a   b b    c             d . In this I want to extract b b.

Comment: the other answer have given the solution, just use `%part[2]%`

Comment: `for /F "tokens=2 delims=_" %%a in ("%string:  =_%") do for /F "tokens=*" %%b in ("%%a") do echo "%%b"` Just use an unused character to replace the space-space..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Collected from various comments: Tokens are delimited by two or more spaces; You need the second token; Every token may or may not have single spaces)

I commented every step and added an `echo` to show progress.

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set "string=ads ads      d b c    dsad   ds   ads"
echo 1: "%string%"
REM remove first token (delimited by ecactly two spaces):
set "string=%string:*  =%"
echo 2: "%string%"
REM remove leading spaces:
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ("%string%") do set "string=%%a"
echo 3: "%string%"
REM remove third and next tokens (delimited by two or more spaces)
set string=%string:  =&REM %
echo 4: "%string%"
```

Only change to my answer to your previous question is the `for` to remove leading spaces

Comment: Much simpler: `for /F "tokens=2 delims=_" %%a in ("%string:  =_%") do for /F "tokens=*" %%b in ("%%a") do echo "%%b"` Just use an unused character to replace the space-space...

Comment: @Aacini: right. the key here is "an unused character". Without sufficient information about the real text, it's hard to decide what character to use.

Comment: Yes, but I think the OP can easily answer this question...

Answer (score 0):

Notice for future readers:

This answer was posted *before* OP added the significant text `I always want the second token no matter how any spaces are there between first and second tokens.`

Please read the original question before voting/commenting

---

No.

`delims` means that tokens are separated by `any sequence of any of the defined delimiter characters`.

Hence your example string would be processed as 7 separate tokens.

If you were to tell us what you are attempting to do,it may help. The approach taken often depends on the desired results.

Probably this is associated with https://stackoverflow.com/a/48808982/2128947 to which you have yet to respond.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented this incase anyone is interested.

```
@echo off

echo.
set "string=Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name"
echo Parse "%string%"

REM: Parse string delimited by more than one space
for %%R in ("%string:  =" "%") do (

    REM: Filter empty
    if not "%%~R" == "" (
        
        REM: Trim leading space
        for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ("%%~R") do set "part=%%a"
        call echo - "%%part%%"
    )
)

echo.
goto :eof
```

Output:

```
Parse "Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name"
- "Admin State"
- "State"
- "Type"
- "Interface Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal 

set "string=ads ads       d b c    dsad   ds   ads"

set "tok1=%string:  =" & if not defined tok2 set "tok2=%"
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ("%tok2%") do set "tok2=%%a"

echo "%tok2%"
```

If you want to understand the method used, remove the `@echo off` line and carefully review the executed code...